# Cross-browser issue: firefox does not load images from a php file after first load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, cross-browser

I have php code that dynamically generates a fresh captcha image. I have an HTML button that refreshes the captcha image with a new one, via a jquery event handler. Clicking the button (and firing the jquery event handler) produces a new image in chrome and safari -- but not in firefox. What is different in firefox? How can I get it to work in firefox?

The javascript console shows no errors in any browser.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
           $(document).ready(function () {
                     $("#submitButton").click(function(event) {                     
                        $("#captchaText").attr('src', 'cryptographp.inc.php?intro=false'); //this line does not generate a fresh image in firefox
                    });
           });

    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet2.css">

</head>


<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id='header'>
     </div>

      <div id='captchaPanel'>

        <div id='top'>
            <div id='fillerTop'>

            </div>
            <div id='captcha'>
                <img id='captchaText' src='cryptographp.inc.php?intro=false'> </img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id='submitDiv'>
    <input id='submitButton' type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Maybe I need to do this with an explicit AJAX call? Something like this (I am guessing on syntax).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'cryptographp.inc.php?intro=false',
    success: function(data) {  $("#captchaText").attr('src', data); }
});
```

Comment: "Does firefox cache calls to PHP files?" --- firefox has no idea what php file is. There are http request and caching headers.

Comment: what appears in the JavaScript debugger for Ffox / Firebug? Sometimes browsers can let incorrect code execute without issue, so Chrome may be being more lenient on you than FFox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Alternative #1 - Using extra `query string`

A very simple way to make sure the image isn't loaded from the cache is to add an extra `query string` as a parameter (no need of reading it on the `server side`), and so there's no way the same `URL` is used twice (*on the same computer*).

In this case I've used the `milliseconds since epoch` by using `Date().getTime()`.

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
$("#captchaText").attr('src', 'cryptographp.inc.php?intro=false&time=' + now);
```

This will result in requesting `URL` such as these:

```
cryptographp.inc.php?intro=false&time=1379998715616
cryptographp.inc.php?intro=false&time=1379998715618
cryptographp.inc.php?intro=false&time=1379998715636
etc...
```

---

## Alternative #2 - Disable HTTP cache with PHP

You can also disable the caching in your `cryptographp.inc.php` with the following code (this might be a good idea even if you choose *Alternative #1*):

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Expires: on, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

- For further reading: [Disable HTTP Cache With PHP](http://www.paulund.co.uk/disable-http-cache-with-php) (The code is taken from there).

Like *Nathaniel Granor* said in the comments, on some browsers changing images' `src attribute` to the same `URL` might not result in a new `HTTP request`, so it's advisable that you'll switch it first to a different location.

For example (JS):

```
  $("#captchaText").attr('src', 'temp.png')
                   .attr('src', 'cryptographp.inc.php?intro=false');
```

- P.S - In this case I suggest that `temp.png` will be a **real file** containing a very small image (such as `1px * 1px` transparent image).

Comment: Yes- it seems possible that the issue is related to the fact that you are swapping out the <img> src attribute with an identical value. Firefox may choose not to call the server again since it believes it has the proper file already.

Additionally or alternatively to Itay's suggestion, you could modify your php file to emit a header specifying that browsers should not cache the file.

Comment: Your 1st WAY worked , though 2nd didnt work.after all i got the work done :)